# Is case-insensitive comparison of string possible for 'where' clause in vuex ORM?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, where-clause

While filtering data from the store, I need to check whether 'name' field of the data is 'stackoverflow'. So I use:

```
data() {
 myname: 'stackoverflow'
},
computed: {
  user() {
   return this.$store.getters['entities/users/query']().where('name', myname).first();
  }
}
```

It works perfectly if the name is given as 'stackoverflow', but not for 'StackOverflow'. Can the 'where' clause be modified so that it checks case insensitive?

Comment: I i don't understand ['entities/uers/quer']().where, how did you find that syntax?

Comment: @Bergur That's the syntax of vuex ORM. They creates entities for each modules and we can query/delete/insert data from/to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used the vuex-orm but i think this should work, according to the docs

https://vuex-orm.github.io/vuex-orm/guide/store/retrieving-data.html#simple-where-clauses

```
computed: {
  user() {
   return this.$store.getters['entities/users/query']().where(user => user.name.toUpperCase() === this.myname.toUpperCase()).first();
  }
}
```

Or even

```
computed: {
  user() {
   return this.$store.getters['entities/users/query']().where('name', value  => value.toUpperCase() === this.myname.toUpperCase()).first();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..! It worked. But I didn't find this syntax on 'https://vuex-orm.github.io/vuex-orm/guide/store/retrieving-data.html#simple-where-clauses'.